# Shiny App R; Not taking Input

Tags: r, filter, shiny

I am trying to write a shiny app and I am having trouble. My goal: make a word cloud that takes Year as the input. Right now it is printing the same words for each year indicating that it is not taking the input, any idea on how to fix this? Thanks so much!

Here is my ui.R file:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title
  headerPanel("Word Cloud"),
  # Sidebar panel for inputs
  sidebarPanel(
    #using the select input function to have users choose a year
    selectInput("year","Choose a Year:",
                choices = NYT_tokens_freq$Year),
    #actionButton("update", "Change"),
    hr(),
    sliderInput("maximum","Max. Number of Words",
                min=1, max=20, value=100)
  ),
  # Main panel for displaying outputs
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("wmplot")
  )
)
```

Here is my server.R file:

```
library(shiny)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(tidyverse)

NYT_tokens <- read.csv("NYT_tokens_freq.csv")

server <- function(input, output) {
  terms <- reactive({
  input$year
  })



  output$wmplot <- renderPlot({
    NYT_tokens_freq%>%
    filter(Year == input$year)
    wordcloud(words = NYT_tokens_freq$word, scale= c(1,0.5),
                max.words=input$maximum, random.order=FALSE,
                colors=brewer.pal(5, "Dark2"))
  })
  }
```

Comment: 2 issues in your server file: 1. you should be using `terms()` instead of `input$year` in your `filter()` call. 2. The filtering should be done in a separate `reactive()` call (say assign to `NY_tokens_reactive`, and then reference `NY_tokens_reactive()$word` as your first argument to `wordcloud()`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I am still slightly confused if you had any further insight, it would be appreciated! server <- function(input, output) {
  terms <- reactive({
    input$year
  }
  
  
  output$wmplot <- renderPlot({
    NYT_tokens_freq%>%
    filter(Year == terms)
    #word <- NYT_tokens_freq$word
    #n <- NYT_tokens$n
    #filter(n == input$maximum)
    #wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)
    wordcloud(words = NYT_tokens_freq$word, scale= c(1,0.5),
                max.words=input$maximum, random.order=FALSE,
                colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
  })

Comment: That is extremely difficult to read. Can you edit your question instead?